# In airflow, how to get default value as ds inside jinja template

Tags: airflow, jinja2, airflow-2.x, mwaa

In airflow dag, how to default to ds within jinja templating.
For example,

```
script_args = { '--previousRunDt': '{{ prev_execution_date_success |default(ds)}}' }'
```

Here when prev_execution_date_success  is none, I need ds as default value. But it is evaluating to None

Answer (score 1):

In Jinja, [the `default()` filter will be used if the original value is not defined/missing](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default).

You could simply use an `or` statement here like:

```py
script_args = { '--previousRunDt': '{{ prev_execution_date_success or ds }}' }'
```